# Difference between Adjacent strong edge coloring and vertex distinguishing strong edge coloring

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

What is the exact difference between the adjacent strong edge coloring and vertex distinguishing proper edge coloring of graphs? [This](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271532/1-s2.0-S0893965900X00870/1-s2.0-S0893965902800155/main.pdf?x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEA4aCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHRKb120kP%2FwQhnRcSrQDPRzIKPme8d91kUN08DmaqFqAiEA7gdo49PS3%2BVceB57%2Bxe5bGz1dYjoY8tpQxLqK8o%2B9u8q2gMIJhACGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDGpsS%2BezsyVKPG34aiq3A1JmJRxEdQZL5wkkVckavA%2BGEgwcdt2g6AMX0DZoRHbx4I2ohJhmmI%2BQ9YUrbiI0T%2FL%2Bz6ni%2FraAL5JZcZ%2BTVSdq92OHF8v9k%2FIjvXNOFRG%2Fex5V25To%2F6u9Lwdov40uwC%2FKi3LHusE9m2%2FHvcviwFurK7ZNOOoaoWA42oDQalcsBKEZ34ro10tqkfGEEfWNIjshg8twTAe3mgJkgElbQnb2PqGciw5FTY0KssuTKrsGckRrtr5XPLstMYX4UUnM8Wz%2FNnI4O0ss%2B02u5u6FfkEcsfUgSTjPX7gpZUJfXK7voYJqh%2BxeD4tf03FDlnC7wK2NBezhpkoJKhegqW44uU0MS35lEP1Nxo1PC1V%2BZ4JMNIaxJMAzwGs6lYvuK0dl1swB4NRS8XW6h5G9hZcFOW%2FCYjPBVYNHHapj4YHweZfkQousDCWJgd%2F2PKnK0VjlpglGNdg1bcGsn63WQknX4rYloPgUEem%2FBkrbUlNY9BJQOpE141JEL25jKzt%2FeRclcdvz5IEvT1xgZwoLK%2FQqQJo0d5AHpY0RRzKHnOuo31Q36WQJwPRl88j6M7LxipLyMuiUQuluseIw3uWt5wU6tAHKqgBtKA8tG9JKql1K%2FaaEla1%2B8RfJgnU0KNZubNwYmcEhURhTyJ7I5tmv1GVV6PZge6WHHpSm6PCo9jY0OakMDgQd9pon9NNj2b82XENvCt%2FB89wKG901yDECP7LC%2BUrvCZW1sfRkuRK04Ly9haiK%2B%2BTlcs%2BegkAOh%2FRdPID6h35g2RfBxex657MMasWAzI8vmcE18fPpgKZNy5%2FuU1wPKSOLkRl6LulArVkv1V9ijq4BYFk%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAQ3PHCVTYQGZLEWOT&Expires=1558940590&Signature=HCqhXZO2vbc5GUMcP6c6a4s9T%2FA%3D&hash=480a51fc287ea34c655f409041f8265276d92c9d8ee2f7c16d65784488801b9a&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0893965902800155&tid=spdf-389c07c4-6145-4659-835a-fc903aa59d97&sid=6d0a6bba7c02e34ad2983ca31897a4a2bf0agxrqb&type=client) paper refers to the fact that the adjacent strong edge coloring of all graphs without $K_2$ or $C_5$ component is less than $\Delta+2$ where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree of the graph as an open conjecture, but, whereas [this](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272566/1-s2.0-S0095895600X00263/1-s2.0-S0095895698918846/main.pdf?x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIC%2FgaGVkHNS1QD49aev5SGQYkU38TsG8q1FTKkHl8V7jAiBahKjN74zgHKyjtTfMYeI2ncveWNbtKo0ED33ChflHGiraAwgpEAIaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMBi8e%2B0VWQ6r21RhAKrcDtEJJJ%2FYVR%2BpUvF3yaZXw1jvCPK90a5Z1%2FoqNwfw8U%2FcVwUhvwdZXebR3d17Y8cn1dGkB1vLk2a9g6B65%2BX%2F9eI0ouAWX0K%2BPQZj9keNIp0WXRVT%2FF5AZlE6%2B%2FjfIAz9BcSwEWGpRqo13USjPnGPath2q400Iv2WW03n7jGye%2FYPLV2NQqor4U9MXIaxprNt7envLDN7696L6ZnmC%2F5r2mtit5dpntpXKx65UMXSdHDdl8tUpEfpn48qhNm2UuVQCOrNrod03Sd0UsyOXuMK9bOW%2ByRE%2FPhYUH0gjrlPIu1HCJz%2FDn9yM8sdKVRQnX3KqWj5gwTKsF%2F7nOo9zFzE8Z58xXZCIGBld%2BF1hhoKmNA6wROoq%2BLEpUboUytLTPtL2yZvrfKEwN55ICHVuXOgxd0koGA9XKWe4UAyOKxJ9kRRJg7MeFIgjop%2BdM5xnOBhVM9ppFmaEMo8PN6Wha9rGg8lAAOmpYdTfT9TkZXPi%2BjPeBEpkGfB%2BsjZ3bUFOumyj5zXUQwG9g%2Fy%2FBAYSqg2antN1KLwUfRkXGjTpGPXd9gkUeOQuhgmPt%2FQADkoM0eBZGFSr6yCY7TCOuq7nBTq1AeIn1myI65eT4RPGYohTfWVhzT7hjoqX0bb%2BzRlUuEH%2BqyJKxVVhjxSSnOYJghNc8ZUjmmbFn69wxHLBoDKcvotjjry5PyOwk7ZAdQ31o5055lS5okpPqKEombflScDBubpw9%2FHaxBtdMgkCZv2sm8g%2B8Ustpt0NT2WY%2FXTF5jdSFqJi5WFP%2F%2Fg6h0BuFCjUxqZ6Fhu0c3ds%2FcswjMoyUixNrla2SfoC4KvluvYLQUTjD56%2FYLU%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAQ3PHCVTYVWAWQO4L&Expires=1558950143&Signature=u2CvcFlPdOgVfQLGGMvL9AEFsZQ%3D&hash=33848fe4fedfeb47db3f29b1900441723e26b7707e1f385c550a57212e0094ee&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0095895698918846&tid=spdf-2c8ac949-35dc-43dc-bc7d-e255dadf2cda&sid=6d0a6bba7c02e34ad2983ca31897a4a2bf0agxrqb&type=client) paper gives a proof that the vertex distinguishing proper edge coloring is less than $\Delta+2$. But, the definitions seem to coincide. Am I missing something here? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Without reading anything very closely (sincerely) it would seem that the 1999 paper proved the number is at most $|V(G)| + 1$ whereas the 2002 paper strengthens this to an upper bound of $\Delta + 2$.  No?

Comment: @PatDevlin oh so silly! I was in the mood of complete graph($\Delta=n-1$), thereby implying that $|V(G)+1|=\Delta+2$. Anyways, so the two terms(vertex distinguishing and adjacent strong edge coloring) are synonymous right?